# Get SamAccountName from AD

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I need some help with this script.

I'm trying to take some csv file found user with employeeid and get back SamAccountName, DisplayName to csv file.

```
 $csv_data = Import-Csv -Path C:\Scripts\test2.scv -Delimiter "," | Select-Object DisplayName ,SamAccountName | Out-File -FilePath C:\Scripts\test3.scv
```

[example scv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkG6a.png)

```
Import-CSV -Path "$home\desktop\Scripts\test5.scv" | ForEach-Object {

$ADUserObject = Get-ADUser -Filter "employeeID -eq '$($_.employeeID)'" -Properties employeeID, sAMAccountName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

}
```

maybe something like this, but still not working :(

Comment: Maybe a typo - but both test2 and tes5 csv you are importing has the extension scv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were pretty close, or maybe even there already. But here's a clean way to do it. Also note that you use '.scv' instead of '.csv', don't know if that is intended.

```
$csv = Import-CSV -Path "$home\desktop\Scripts\test5.csv"
$csvOutput = "$home\desktop\Scripts\test3.csv"
$object = @()
foreach($employee in $csv){
    $ADUserObject = Get-ADUser -Filter "employeeID -eq '$($employee.employeeID)'" -Properties samAccountName, displayName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if($ADUserObject){
        $object += New-Object psobject -Property @{
            displayName = $ADUserObject.displayName
            samAccountName = $ADUserObject.SamAccountName
        }
    }else{
        Write-Host "No employee found for $($employee.employeeId)" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}
if($object){
    $object | Select-Object displayName, samAccountName | Export-Csv -Path $csvOutput -Delimiter "," -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Note that you can use '-append' to add the content to the csv instead of overwriting it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have related question , i am beginner though . ....If there are subdomains (childa,abc.com childb.abc.com, childc.abc.com )and contains same samaccountname(123456789) how the AD is gonna do authentication ?? Is it going to check the subdomains one by one so that user can be authenticated ?? my app uses only samaccountname as login id.  What is the password is different for this samaccount in each of the subdomain... ??

Comment: You can only have 1 samAccountName on all subdomains. If for instance your account is samAccountName 'test'. It's UPN is for instance 'test@abc.com'. But now it is not possible to create 'test@childb.abc.com' with samAccountName 'test'. It will say it already exists. The samAccountName and the UPN must be unique

Comment: Also, the authentication is done automatically because the samAccountName is unique it will find the correct childdomain.

Comment: thanks Bernard, However i am in this kind of situation and want to understand the authentication happens. https://help.duo.com/s/article/2061?language=en_US....

Comment: We created root AD because the application which we are using is having the ability to connect only one AD.  We also saw the sameaccountname =12345 exist in 3 childdomains and UPN of those accounts are 12345@childa.abc.com ,12345@childb.abc.com  and 12345@childc.abc.com  ... App send the userid as 12345 and password to root AD while login funcation. Now how root decides which childdomain to be considered for login ?? Is there is any option in AD set the precedence or priority to choose subdomain ?

Comment: For what I know it will just take the account with the lowest GUID numbers. So it is really not failsafe. You should really consider using UPN, objectSID or objectGUID as unique identifiers.